# I am confused about the error There was an error getting the type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

When I try to create a view using create template and using model class and data context class, I get an error:

> There was an error getting the type 'project.Models.Tablename'. Try Rebuilding the project.

How to fix it?

I have already tried to delete the model and again scaffold it using ado.net

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception messages :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states `Try Rebuilding the project`. Go to the Build Menu and Rebuild, that should clear your error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, This worked. I searched for a lot of solutions but there was not even a single answer.